# Xamarin Forms width behave as expected

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

(edited, see below)

I want to define an component's width embedded in a FlexLayout in Xamarin Forms and it doesn't behave like i would expect in multiple ways:

**1) the full screen width that i get isn't the same as the width that is required to fill the screen with the component.**

Having a OnePlus 6 my density according to Xamarin is 2.625 and my width is 1080 px, which gives me a DP width of ca. 411. When i check the width of the root layout (covering 100% of the screen width) it is also ca. 411 so the calculation is correct i assume.

```
        double density = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Density;
        double screenWidth = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Width;
        double tileWidth = screenWidth / density;
```

When i define my xaml as follows:

```
        <FlexLayout AlignItems="Start" JustifyContent="Start"  Wrap="Wrap" AlignContent="Start" BackgroundColor="Yellow">
            <Frame HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="411" BackgroundColor="#66DC1A" BorderColor="Red">
                <RelativeLayout>
                    <Label Text="TEST"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </Frame>
        </FlexLayout>
```

... And i enter 411 (or usine Binding to get the value) it seems like everything is correct here, since the component's border is visible on all sides. BUT apparently the component never exceeds the bounds of the screen, because if i entered a width of 1000 it would look exactly the same.
trying to figure out what's the actual 100% i approached it step by step and the result was 371.

so first confusion: the screen widths is supposed to be 411, the component reaches 100% with 371

**2) getting a third of the width isn't a third on the screen**

let's assume the 371 DP is my 100% of the screen, if i wanted to place 3 components in a row and calculated the width of the component as a third of the 371 (ca. 123), the displayed component is much bigger than the third of the screen. And there's no defined margin, padding or borders that would amount in that huge of a difference. Again i did an approximation and the width that allowed me to place 3 components in a row is 97 (instead of the calculated 123). Doing the reverse calculation, according to this result the 100% would need to be 291 instead of the 371

second confusion: calculating a fraction of the width doesn't result in the same result for the displayed component

to visualize it a little bit i let it draw the following xaml which resulted in the design further below:

```
    <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout x:Name="mainLayout">
        <FlexLayout AlignItems="Start" JustifyContent="Start"  Wrap="Wrap" AlignContent="Start" BackgroundColor="Yellow">
            <Frame HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="1000" BackgroundColor="#66DC1A" BorderColor="Red">
                <RelativeLayout>
                    <Label Text="1000"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </Frame>
            <Frame HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="371" BackgroundColor="#66DC1A" BorderColor="Red">
                <RelativeLayout>
                    <Label Text="371"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </Frame>
            <Frame HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="291" BackgroundColor="#66DC1A" BorderColor="Red">
                <RelativeLayout>
                    <Label Text="291"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </Frame>
            <Frame HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="97" BackgroundColor="#66DC1A" BorderColor="Red">
                <RelativeLayout>
                    <Label Text="97"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </Frame>
            <Frame HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="97" BackgroundColor="#66DC1A" BorderColor="Red">
                <RelativeLayout>
                    <Label Text="97"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </Frame>
            <Frame HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="97" BackgroundColor="#66DC1A" BorderColor="Red">
                <RelativeLayout>
                    <Label Text="97"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </Frame>

            <Frame HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="291" BackgroundColor="#66DC1A" BorderColor="Red">
                <RelativeLayout>
                    <Label Text="291"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </Frame>
        </FlexLayout>
        <FlexLayout AlignItems="End" JustifyContent="End"  Wrap="Wrap" AlignContent="Start" BackgroundColor="orange">
            <Frame HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="40" BackgroundColor="#66DC1A" BorderColor="Red">
                <RelativeLayout>
                    <Label Text="40"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </Frame>
        </FlexLayout>
        <AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="blue">
            <Frame HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="160" BackgroundColor="#66DC1A" BorderColor="Red">
                <RelativeLayout>
                    <Label Text="TEST"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </Frame>
            <Frame HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="80" BackgroundColor="#66DC1A" BorderColor="Red">
                <RelativeLayout>
                    <Label Text="TEST"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </Frame>
            <Frame HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="40" BackgroundColor="#66DC1A" BorderColor="Red">
                <RelativeLayout>
                    <Label Text="TEST"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </Frame>
            <Frame HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="20" BackgroundColor="#66DC1A" BorderColor="Red">
                <RelativeLayout>
                    <Label Text="TEST"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </Frame>
            <Frame HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="10" BackgroundColor="#66DC1A" BorderColor="Red">
                <RelativeLayout>
                    <Label Text="TEST"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </Frame>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

[image: example with multiple components]

in the first part i just drew some components with the specified widths that I used to describe my problem. the second block (orange) shows only that i need another component with 40 DP to fill up the screen next to the 291 Block

the third block shows that the width is not linear. I drew multiple blocks on top of each others with the following widths (bottom to top): 160, 80, 40, 20, 10. Again: not to get confused, all displayed components have the same starting point (left) and lay on top of each others.

What am I doing wrong and how can i reliably calculate the width of the components? is there something i am missing? I hope someone can enlighten me here a little :)

thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
Ok, sometimes you need to take a step back to see clear again. It seems like there is a default offset of 40 DP **for Frames** which is added to the width. which means when I set width to 1 the actual width will be 41. that behaviour seems to be consistent and i can work with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infact `Frame` class is a layout used to wrap a view with a border that can be configured with color, shadow, and other options.

It has a border by default(left:20,top:20,right:20,bottom:20).So you think there is a default offset of 40 DP for Frames which is added to the width.

For example you could test it :

```
 <Frame x:Name="frame" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="291" BackgroundColor="#66DC1A" BorderColor="Red">
            <RelativeLayout>
                <Label Text="291"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
 </Frame>
 <Button Text="click" Clicked="Button_Clicked"></Button>
```

then in your page.xaml.cs:

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var w = frame.Width;  // w = 331
        var l = fram0.Padding;// you could the board thickness line below

    }
```

`l = Left=20, Top=20, Right=20, Bottom=20, HorizontalThickness=40, VerticalThickness=40`